# Publish VS 2015 project with SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports

I need to publish my Windows forms application project that has a Microsoft SQL Server database. I was able to publish it and install the project in a different computer, but the database was not published with it. How do I publish the project *with* the database included?

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is connect and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error 26 - Error Location Server/Instance Specified)

I use Visual Studio 2015, Microsoft SQL Server 2016, and SAP Crystal Reports.

Comment: **Microsoft sql server 2015** does not exist

Comment: sorry, edited to 2016

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to add database deployment in each machine then 
a. Each machine should have installed sql-server instance.
b. You will have to proper configuration in `app.config`

[How to deploy or publish Windows app with SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680600/how-to-deploy-or-publish-windows-app-with-sql-server-database) may help you to get your solution.